# Compojure Example from Clojure in Action Not Working

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure

I am working on the Compojure example from Clojure in Action page 232

```
(ns compojure-test.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:use compojure))

(defroutes hello
  (GET "/" (html [:h1 "Hello world"]))
  (ANY "*" [404 "Page not found"]))

(run-server {:port 8080} "/*" (servlet hello))
```

But when I attempt to run it:

```
$ lein run
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: compojure-test.core
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
...
```

it appears that the statement

```
(:use compojure)
```

I have also heard that there was a major change between recent versions of compojure.  What ma I doing wrong in setting up this compojure app?  Is there a good tutorial online to help me get up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try changing your `use` statement to:

`(:use compojure.core)`

That should do it.

I created a boilerplate template a while back for compojure that has a working example you can see [here](https://github.com/leonardoborges/clj-boilerplate/blob/master/src/clj_boilerplate/core.clj).

Even better, if you're using Leiningen - which you should - you can simply create a new compojure project like this:

`$ lein new compojure hello-world`

Checkout compojure's [Getting Started](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Getting-Started) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thanks for the boilerplate.  Quick n00b question, how do I setup my project.clj and how do I run this on localhost?

Comment: I'd recommend using the lein template. Once you create the project, your project.clj should be good to go. Then just run this in your project root: `lein ring server` and it should open up the browser at the root of your webapp. Once this works, all you need is to implement your code.